# How to avoid re-rendering a functional component when a certain prop changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, use-state, react-state

I have a PlayArea component with a number of Card components as children, for a card game.

The position of the cards is managed by the PlayArea, which has a state value called `cardsInPlay`, which is an array of `CardData` objects including positional coordinates among other things. PlayArea passes `cardsInPlay` and `setCardsInPlay` (from `useState`) into each Card child component.

Cards are draggable, and while being dragged they call `setCardsInPlay` to update their own position.

The result, of course, is that `cardsInPlay` changes and therefore *every card re-renders.* This may grow costly if a hundred cards make it out onto the table.

How can I avoid this? Both PlayArea and Card are functional components.

Here's a simple code representation of that description:

```
const PlayArea = () => {
  const [cardsInPlay, setCardsInPlay] = useState([]);

  return (
    <>
      { cardsInPlay.map(card => (
        <Card
          key={card.id}
          card={card}
          cardsInPlay={cardsInPlay}
          setCardsInPlay={setCardsInPlay} />
      }
    </>
  );
}

const Card = React.memo({card, cardsInPlay, setCardsInPlay}) => {
    const onDrag = (moveEvent) => {
       setCardsInPlay(
         cardsInPlay.map(cardInPlay => {
           if (cardInPlay.id === card.id) {
              return {
               ...cardInPlay,
               x: moveEvent.clientX,
               y: moveEvent.clientY
              };
           }
           return cardInPlay;
        }));
      };

      return (<div onDrag={onDrag} />);
   });
```

Comment: Make sure when you're mapping the `cardsInPlay` array to JSX that you provide a proper `key` prop to avoid remounting the instances unnecessarily, and wrap the `Card` component in a `React.memo()` HOC.

Comment: Well that's the odd thing, I already do have both of those.

Comment: Did you mean `const Card = ({ card, cardsInPlay, setCardsInPlay }) => ...`? Note the addition of object destructuring `{ ... }` in the parameter list.

Comment: Oh, yes. I don't have any issues like that in the actual code-- that was just a typo while simplifying. I added the memo/key into the sample code here now too.

Comment: The problem is you're passing the _entire_ `cardsInPlay` array to each `Card` so the props _do_ change. Pass only the element that each card needs to know about. And use the functional `setCardsInPlay()` signature to access the previous state. You don't need to pass down the whole array to get that.

Comment: hm. let me go try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're passing the entire `cardsInPlay` array to each `Card`, so `React.memo()` will still re-render each card because the `props` *have* changed. Only pass the element that each card needs to know about and it will only re-render the card that has changed. You can access the previous `cardsInPlay` using the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) signature of `setCardsInPlay()`:

```
const PlayArea = () => {
  const [cardsInPlay, setCardsInPlay] = useState([]);
  const cards = cardsInPlay.map(
    card => (
      <Card
        key={card.id}
        card={card}
        setCardsInPlay={setCardsInPlay} />
    )
  );

  return (<>{cards}</>);
};

const Card = React.memo(({ card, setCardsInPlay }) => {
  const onDrag = (moveEvent) => {
    setCardsInPlay(
      cardsInPlay => cardsInPlay.map(cardInPlay => {
        if (cardInPlay.id === card.id) {
          return {
            ...cardInPlay,
            x: moveEvent.clientX,
            y: moveEvent.clientY
          };
        }
        return cardInPlay;
      })
    );
  };

  return (<div onDrag={onDrag} />);
});
```

Comment: (In your code example the `Card` is still using `cardsInPlay`, which is no longer passed in as a prop-- I guess the function that's passed in needs to handle that instead of passing in `setCardsInPlay` directly.)

Comment: @temporary_user_name notice that `cardsInPlay` is accepted from the callback passed to `setCardsInPlay`. Just try it, it'll work.

Comment: @temporary_user_name you're familiar with [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), right?

Comment: I never, ever knew that. That is so incredibly useful. Do you know how much react I've written without ever encountering this particular aspect? Wow.

Comment: @temporary_user_name I've written [a lot of react myself](https://github.com/patrickroberts/suspense-service) (hope you don't mind the shameless plug). It pays to read the documentation thoroughly ;)

Comment: Not at all, thanks for the knowledge! While we're on the subject, any idea how to get Typescript to accept the callback? This shows up on the line where I pass the prop in-- ```Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<CardInPlay[]>>' is not assignable to type '(callback: (cardsInPlay: CardInPlay[]) => void) => void'.```

Comment: @temporary_user_name I'm guessing you defined the second type there in the props for `Card`. Change it to the first type.

Comment: Thank you I know. Also, your insight about passing a callback to a setState call has transformed the code for what I'm working on. My gratitude is boundless.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you pass `cardsInPlay` to each `Card` component. It doesn't matter if the array in state changes as long as you pass only the required information to child.

Eg:

```
<Card positionX={cardsInPlay[card.id].x} positionY={cardsInPlay[card.id].y} />
```

will not cause a re-render, because even i the parent array changes, the instance itself is not getting a new prop. But if you pass the whole data to each component :

```
<Card cardsInPlay={cardsInPlay} />
```

it will cause all to re-render because each `Card` would get a new prop for every render as no two arrays,objects are equal in Javascript.

P.S : Edited after seeing sample code

Comment: Thanks! The crux of your suggestion is exactly what I ended up doing, in combination with the useState callback signature option the other answer suggested.